# Block yum from installing or updating a package (mariadb) in future

Tags: centos, mysql, redhat, yum, mariadb

We've just set up a Centos 8 server, and had to install MySQL on there instead whilst migrating services for the time.

All is working, we've removed MariaDB and MySQL is working fine.

What I would like to do, is block MariaDB from every being installed with `yum` by accident via some dependency (so happy if we later remove it from some exclude list for example).

I was looking at `/etc/yum.conf` and the line `exclude=` but it's unclear if that's just for updates, and if someone typed `yum install somepackage` that had a mariadb dependency if that would overwrite our mysql install.

So, is there a way to permanently block a package from being found or installed, and also to try and indicate that it's blocked if you try ?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194714/157036) from the unix stack exchange is pretty much on point.

It essentially says yum won't allow you to exclude a package as a dependency because then it would be doing a terrible job at being a package manager. There is a work around, in that you can use:

`rpm -i --nodeps [package].rpm`

to install the package without any dependencies, but then you'll be stuck managing that package manually.

Personally, I would just add the `exclude=mariadb*` line to your `yum.conf` and live with the risk that somewhere down the road mariadb gets accidentally installed as a dependency.